# Добавление bootstrap к rails по урокам Michael Hartl

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

Я пытаюсь добавить бутстрап к рельсам выдает такую ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите на [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391116/nomethoderror-in-pageshome-undefined-method-environment-for-nilnilclass) и на [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436445/nomethoderror-in-pageswelcome-after-installing-the-bootstrap-gem).

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых было бы понятнее, если бы вы привели здесь свой custom.css.scss.

Во-вторых, если вы и так уже используете scss, то `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`

Официальный гем специально для нас. Подключается двумя строчками.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails посмотрите эту ссылку, здесь популярно все написанно, не думаю что будут затыки.